# Looping through keys in a dictionary and the starting over from the first key using python

Tags: python, loops

FIRST, I know that dictionaries don't really have any order. In this case we can rely on the order since they are being inputed correctly by the user. For an example, if I have...

```
dict = {"one": 1, "two": 2}
```

The key "one" would be the first to be used and "two" would be the next.

At this point I have this code to simulate each turn someone is taking.

```
print("WHEN YOU ARE FINISHED ADDING PLAYERS TYPE \"done\".")
while name_input.lower() != "done":
    name_input = input("Type the player's name you wish to add and press 
enter: ") 
    players[name_input] = [5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
del players[name_input]
print(players)

for index, (key, value) in enumerate(players.items()):
```

The for loop above helps me simulate a turn for each player (each player will be a key in the dictionary). However, it only allows me to loop through each player once and I would like it to loop until a condition is met instead. Please let me know how to change the loop or if there is another way to do this.

If you need more details just ask! I'll be happy to get back to you super quick.

Comment: `while True:  <for loop>`?

Comment: **or** you can `from itertools import cycle` then iterate over `for index, (key, value) in cycle(enumerate(players.items()))` and then simply `break` from within the loop whenever `<condition>` happens

Comment: ok ill try that

Comment: This works well thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to loop over a iterable infinite times.

```
from itertools import cycle
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(cycle(players.items())):
    # This is a infinite loop
    if condition:
        break
```